# MediaWiki - tables not showing

Tags: mediawiki

Using MediaWiki 1.18, phpMyAdmin 2.10.1 , mysql 5.0.67, Semantic MediaWiki 1.7.1.

I'm trying to create tables in my mediawiki but they just appear as text.  I thought this was a part of the base code, but perhaps there is an addon I have to install?  I've tried:

```
{| class="prettytable"
|-
|
fdasfda

|
afda

|-
|
fdafda

|
fdafdsa

|}
```

This just displays as {| class="prettytable"|-|fdasfda|afda|-|fdafda|fdafdsa|}

Any idea how to solve this?

Update: I just enabled the two beta options:

Enable enhanced editing toolbar
Enable dialogs for inserting links, tables and more

After doing that, I can use the toolbar to create a table, which is visible after editing, but attempting to copy/paste code for a table still does not work.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=486098899)

Comment: Yes I know, it's very strange :-/

Comment: @user1088537 I have same problem, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just used `class="wikitable"` instead.

Comment: even with `class="wikitable"` problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

Your line-feeds may be your problem.  I've had issues with that in the past.  Try..

```
{| class="prettytable"
|-
| fdasfda
| afda
|-
| fdafda
| fdafdsa
|}
```

Also, your `class="prettytable"` css could be broken.. Try the table without it.